# How to pass link list to a function in c

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

How can I pass the head pointer of a link list to a function? I wrote 2 programs to insert 10 elements in a link list at the end. One of them runs successfully and other one does not. I could figure out the problem with my second code, but I can't find the solution Here are my codes and their outputs.

Code 1(Successful one)-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int item;
    struct node *next;
}snode;

void main()
{
    system("clear");
    snode *head,*p,*new,*last;
    int i;
    last=(snode *)malloc(sizeof(snode));
    head=(snode *)malloc(sizeof(snode));

    head->next=NULL;
    last->next=NULL;

    printf("Enter 10 numbers to be inserted at the end\n");
    for(i=0;i<=9;i++)
    {
        new=(snode *)malloc(sizeof(snode));
        scanf("%d",&new->item);
        if(i==0)
        {
            head=last=new;
        }
        else
        {
            last->next=new;
            new->next=NULL;
            last=new;
        }
    }

    p=head;
    printf("Items in the link list are: ");
    while(p!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d->",p->item);
        p=p->next;
    }
    printf("NULL\n");
}
```

output-

```
Enter 10 numbers to be inserted at the end
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
Items in the link list are: 0->1->2->3->4->5->6->7->8->9->NULL
```

Code 2(Failure)-Changes done by the insert function are not reflected in main()

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int item;
    struct node *next;
}snode;

void insert(snode *,snode *);

void main()
{
    system("clear");
    snode *head,*p,*last;
    int i;
    last=(snode *)malloc(sizeof(snode));
    head=(snode *)malloc(sizeof(snode));

    (head)->next=NULL;
    (last)->next=NULL;

    insert(head,last);

    p=head;
    printf("Items in the link list are: ");
    while(p!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d->",p->item);
        p=p->next;
    }
    printf("NULL\n");
}

void insert(snode *head,snode *last)
{
    int i;
    snode *new;
    printf("Enter 10 numbers to be inserted at the end\n");
    for(i=0;i<=9;i++)
    {
        new=(snode *)malloc(sizeof(snode));
        scanf("%d",&new->item);
        if(i==0)
        {
            head=last=new;
        }
        else
        {
            (last)->next=new;
            new->next=NULL;
            last=new;
        }
    }
}
```

Output-

```
Enter 10 numbers to be inserted at the end
0 1 2 3 4 5 6  7 8 9
Items in the link list are: 0->NULL
```

I know I should use call by reference method. But I am unable to understand where do I use `*` operator and `&` operator.

Comment: here's a minimal example to reproduce the problem: `void add_one(int a) { a += 1; }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function `insert` gets the pointers by value, so when it modifies head, it modifies the local copy of the pointer. `insert` does not change the `head` variable you defined in `main`.

You need to change `insert` to taking the pointers by reference:

```
void insert(snode **head, snode **last);
```

and then in main pass the addresses of the pointers:

```
insert(&head, &last);
```

Looking at your code I see that you initialize head and last to malloc-ed structs. Are you sure that you want that? Normally you set head=last=NULL for an empty list.

BTW, you should compile with a high warning level. This helps you identify errors.